# Find a period with specific characteristics in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a metereological DataFrame, indexed by TimeStamp, and I want to find all the possible periods of 24 hours present in the DataFrame with these conditions:

1. at least 6 hours of Rainfalls with Temperature > 10°C
2. a minimum of 6 consecutive hours of Relative Humidity > 90%.

The hours taken in consideration may also be 'overlapped' (a period with 6 hours of both RH > 90 and Rainfalls > 0 is sufficient).

A sample DataFrame with 48 hours can be created by:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TimeStamp': pd.date_range('1/5/2015 00:00:00', periods=48, freq='H'), 
                   'Temperature': np.random.choice( [11,12,13], 48),
                   'Rainfalls': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   'RelativeHumidity': [95,95,95,95,95,95,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,85,85,85,85,85,85,85,85,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80,80]})

df = df.set_index('TimeStamp')
```

In output I just want the indexes of the various TimeStamps from which every period with the mentioned characteristics starts. In the case of the sample df, only the first TimeStamp is given in output.

I have tried to use the `df.rolling()` function but I managed to find only the 6 hours of consecutive RH > 90.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood your question right. This example will find all *groups* where Temperature > 10 and RH > 90 of minimum length of 6 and then prints the first index of these groups:

```py
x = (df.Temperature > 10).astype(int) + (df.RelativeHumidity > 90).astype(int)
out = (
    x.groupby((x != x.shift(1)).cumsum().values)
    .apply(lambda x: x.index[0] if (x.iat[0] == 2) and len(x) > 5 else np.nan)
    .dropna()
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
1   2015-01-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Maybe I explain my problem badly, I need to retrieve all the possible periods of 24 hours in which there are: (6 hours of rainfalls>0 with temperature>10°C) AND (6 consecutive hours of RH>90%) (this "hours" can be overlapped, I mean if there are 6 consecutive hours of RH>90 and in that hours it rained it's ok).